# Unable to scrape text from popup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

When I go to the below link and click on the details button, a popup will open. I want to get data from this popup, but I'm unable to get any kind of text from this popup. However, I can access every other element. But when I try to get the text from these elements it gives me an empty string.

link: http://www.finduniversity.ph/universities/university-of-the-philippines-diliman/diploma-courses/

```
>>> driver.find_element_by_class_name('DetailsHeader').text
```

output:

```
u''
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my approach? 
I'm using python 2.7 with selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of `div` nodes on base page with class name `DetailsHeader`, but they are hidden. `text` property returns text of visible elements only. If element is not visible, `text` returns an empty string. `driver.find_element_by_class_name('DetailsHeader')` gives you the first element from base page, but not from modal. That's why you got empty string.

If you need the one from modal window, you need more specific selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#Modal div.DetailsHeader").text
```

Comment: Welcome ) You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem